# Continuous update feature/event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, continuous

Is there some kind of update feature like in C# for Visual Studio 2012 in vb.net? (so that it will continuously check to see if an if statement is fulfilled)

Comment: Could you elaborate what you're talking about? Are you talking about the Watch window?

Comment: I don't know what that is but say I have a label and every time you click the label it adds one to itself. Say I wanted there to be a message saying "1000" once the label gets to 1000. I know I would need something like " If Label1 = ("1000") then                                Msgbox("1000")"                                                      but where would I insert this code to make it continuously check the status of the label.

Comment: Well, you talked about a *update feature like in C#*. So my question is what C# feature are you talking about? Also, if you create an event handler that alters the text of a label, you can put your check into that very event handler itself.

Comment: I mean the update function that runs the code every frame

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim iClicks As Integer = 0

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
    iClicks += 1
    Label1.Text = iClicks.ToString()

    If iClicks = 1000 Then
        MessageBox.Show("1000 reached!")
    End If
End Sub
```

It's better to have a integer counter than checking the string value and performing conversion each time. As you can see, the code checks the click counter each time you click the label.

---

If you want to check the value periodically, add a Timer and perform the check in its event:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If iClicks = 1000 Then
        MessageBox.Show("1000 reached!")
    End If
End Sub
```

But consider the need to do this, because maybe it's not necessary and will decrease the performance comparing it with the other way.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way of doing this, but what I've done when I need a constant "update" function, is just use a Timer, then handle the Ticks.

Easiest way of implementing it is to go to the form designer, in the Toolbox, under Components, drag a timer onto the form. Double-click it to add a handle for its Tick event.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If WhateverYoureLookingFor = True
        'Do stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

This is obviously VB, but easy to convert to C#.